# What is the best way to host content for user testing and revoke access?

Tags: apache, testing, amazon-ec2, dynamic, temporary

I am wanting to host an application on our EC2 Apache server and allow users to test it for a time and then revoke their testing privileges.
I believe that cname and alias records are out of the question since those effect the domain in its entirety rather than just a single page.

Comment: How will users authenticate to your application? It should control access for test users. If you are asking how to host a separate 'test' version of your system, you could put it under a subdomain, such as `test.example.com`.

Comment: I would like to just offer a public URL that would be usable by the tester once and then become unusable rather than an authentication system. The url given to them would be unique and therefore their authentication in a way.

Comment: You would need to implement this logic in your own application.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up security groups in such a way that instances only allow inbound traffic from the CLB's security group.
Check this one here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html

Comment: I don't quite follow. Security groups would require knowing the end users ip address if you were wanting to limit traffic by that end user, no?